# Custom built kernel fails to install correctly - Centos7

Tags: linux-kernel, centos, rpmbuild

I am attempting to build and install multiple kernels on my machine, all of the exact same release (`4.19.10`, found [here](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.19.10.tar.xz)) but with different preemption models (for benchmarking).  I was successful with initial vanilla kernel build and install, but all subsequent installs have not been bootable.

I am building the kernels as rpm packages.  Again all are the exact same except for 2 changes in `make menuconfig`:

- `General Setup >> Local version - append to kernel release` - Here I add a string to indicate preemption model, such as `-lld` for low-latency desktop
- `General Setup >> Preemption Model` - Here I select the preemption model

All of them (with and without `CONFIG_RT_PREEMPT` patch) build fine with no errors.
I am installing with `rpm -ivh kernel-4.19.10_lld-1.x86_64.rpm`, which appears successful until it reaches 100% and hangs.  Eventually I kill the install with `ctrl+c` and check what is running with `top` and can see `grub2-editenv` is still running.

From here, a few different things can happen but it all ends up the same.  Reboot usually hangs, a 2nd reboot either brings me to grub command line or back to the command line with `Welcome to emergency mode!`.

I can add the new kernel to grub with `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`, which has no issues. But regardless of selecting the boot image from the grub command line directly or adding it to grub and selecting it during boot, I get the same text:

```
error: invalid magic number.
error: you need to load the kernel first
```

I recognize that there might not be enough info here to identify my issue, but I was hoping to at least get some direction and answer a few questions:

- Is utilizing `General Setup >> Local version - append to kernel release` sufficient enough to make these kernels unique so that they may be installed along side one another?
- Are these symptoms indicative of a bad build, incorrectly configured rpm spec, or just a bad grub configuration?

Thanks

---

Update: I was able to upgrade my kernel with `rpm -Uvh kernel-4.19.10_lld-1.x86_64.rpm` successfully and have it correctly boot, although I could not do that with one of the other kernels.  Not sure what that indicates, but I'm thinking the issue is probably trying to install the same kernel versions in parallel and the builds themselves are probably OK.

---

Update 2:
I ditched the rpm solution and tried just `make modules_install` and `make install`. Installs no issues, but then running `grub2-mkconfig` hangs. Booting hangs at black screen, rebooting takes me to grub command line. Then manually loading the kernel does not give any errors but booting ends up with a kernel panic right after the hardware is identified. Message is `Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount`.

Probably related - I built the first (working)  kernel on a VM (intel i7 hardware), but have been building the others on an intel atom e3950 chipset.  I'm thinking that might be the issue because the menuconfig ends up different. I dont think I've had a healthy build on that chipset yet.

Comment: The stuff that is "hanging" is probably all the magic it does in `%post` involving setting up `grub`, `rdinit`, etc. by using `dracut`. You should be able to see what it was up to with `top` or `htop`. It might not be truly hung; I have seen it take minutes in the past.

Comment: So, an interesting thing is I actually ditched the rpm solution and tried just `make modules_install` and `make install`. Installs no issues, but then running `grub2-mkconfig` hangs. Booting hangs at black screen, rebooting takes me to grub command line. Then manually loading the kernel does not give any errors but booting ends up with a kernel panic right after the hardware is identified. Message is `Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount`.  I built the first (workinf)  kernel on a VM, but have been building the others on an intel atom chipset.  Im thinking that might be the issue

Comment: Well, like everything else, you need it to build / work first before you can package it with RPMs.